# Removing a class from UL LI but not UL LI UL LI with jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm modifying an accordion script to add the class `active` to the link that gets clicked, but  for sub items, I'm having an issue.

Basically, if you click on a child of the accordion, I need it to also add the class active without removing it from the parent. Like this

```
parent-item
parent-item (active)
   sub-item
   sub-item (active)
   sub-item
parent-item
parent-item
```

Here's the bit of script currently:

```
$("#menu li a").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

Thanks, just post a comment if you need clarification.

EDIT:

The children elements aren't technically children of the same thing, so `.parent()` won't work.

```
<li>
    <a href="#">parent-item</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sub-item</a>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

This will remove the .active on the same level elements

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
$("#menu li a").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).parent().addClass("active");
```

After removing the active class just add it back to the selected item *and* its parent.

EDIT: Looking at your HTML fragment you should be able to walk back up as far as you need and then come back down. e.g.

```
$("#menu li a").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).parent().parent().children("a").addClass("active");
```

Comment: That would work, but unfortunately they're not direct children. I've added an HTML example in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$("#menu > ul").removeClass("active");
$(this).parent("li").parent("ul").addClass("active");
```

Should add an active class to the relevant parent-item.

Answer (score 0):

This example maybe will help you

```
<ul id='menu'>
<li>
    <a>MElement1</a>
</li>
<li>
     <a>MElement2</a>
 </li>
</ul>
<ul id='menu1'>
<li>
    <a>Element1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>Element2</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.deneme{
    color:red;
}

.deneme1{
color:blue;
}
```

js

```
$('#menu').addClass('deneme')
$('#menu1 li a').addClass('deneme1')

$('#menu').live('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('deneme')
})
$('#menu1 li a').live('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('deneme1')
})
```

and u can check from here http://jsfiddle.net/h7fvW/